# Select from different database rows

Tags: php, mysql, select

The title might not be the best fit for this post, I'm sorry about that!
I've got a problem when selecting result from the database. I got 3 rows in a table called "test1", "test2" and "test3" with the values true or false.
How do i select all results with the value of 1? i dont want to combine them like:

```
WHERE test1 = 1 AND test2 = 1 AND test3 = 1.
```

I want to get all results with the value of 1.

Comment: Please show the table structure...

Comment: You you mean column instead or row?

Comment: Few terminologies may need correction. I think you maybe talking about database column and not row. Although different Database Management app show individual records differently but in proper Jargon of Database, they are called columns. That means, name, age, dob would be columns and not rows. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Rows in a database do not have names, so it is highly unlikely that the rows are called called "test1", "test2" and "test3".

Answer (score 0):

If you mean columns then i don't see any problem with doing it the way you've done it.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE test1 = 1 AND test2 = 1 AND test3 = 1
```

Update #1

```
CREATE PROCEDURE nameofprocedure(
   IN vartest1 INT,
   IN vartest2 INT,
   IN vartest3 INT
)
BEGIN
   SELECT * 
   FROM tablename 
   WHERE test1 = vartest1 AND test2 = vartest1 AND test3 = vartest1

END;
```

Update #2

Then to call the procedure use;

```
CALL nameofprocedure(1, 0, 1); or
CALL nameofprocedure(1, 1, 1); //Mix what ever you like
```

Comment: But let's say that i want also want the results that have the values: test1 = 1, test2 = 0 test3  = 1?

Comment: From what you are saying i think what you are looking for is a stored procedure. where test1, test2, test3 are all variables and can contain any value.

Answer (score 0):

Hey any way u will have the column name ie attribute name so use .forget about each row

```
                select * from table_name WHERE column_name=1.
```